# how to convert columns and rows from oracle database to excel sheet with colors in python

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter, pandas.excelwriter, excel-writer-xlsx

These are the data am getting from oracle database how would I show them in excel sheet with colors tried many ways couldn't figure out, how to fit in the excel sheet as my row width is big. Help would be appreciated.

```
columns = ['aone','bone',cone]
rows  = [["rodfdf.4556.sfsdfdne", 45, null].["rtemp546.44fdfdf", 4, "vision"], 
         ["sfsdfdfdf6656.645", 97, "lib"]]
```

Please help me out, guys. How to show the columns and rows in colors in excel sheet in  python